# How to use response assertion in postman by using " to.be"?

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script, postman-testcase

[image]

I am trying to validate the positive and negative test cases using response assertion, but it didn't give me the expected result.

I am trying to confirm the response using "pm.response.to.be.ok" to get the response as "200" an so on as listed in the screenshot, but it gives me error as

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'to' of undefined

Comment: I would take a look at the spelling of `response` on each of them and also `jason` isn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax in the tests are incorrect and that's why it's throwing an error, it should be something like this:

```
pm.test('Check the response', () => {
    pm.response.to.be.ok
    pm.response.to.have.body()
    pm.response.to.have.jsonBody()
})
```

https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox_api_reference/

Comment: hello, danny thanks for the solution.

It works fine for "to.be.ok" but body and jsonBody(); are not giving result.

Comment: Not giving the result of what? Can you update your original question and provide more screen shots of the error and information about what you're doing. Saying 'It doesn't work" isn't very helpful.